# Looking for better solution - merge statements

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

I have two merge statements one of which uses subset of rows of other. Is there a way to optimize the solution.

#### Statement 1

```
merge into tableA using (select c from tableB where tableA.a=tableB.a)
on (tableA.a = tableB.a and tableA.b= tableB.b) 
when matched update set tableA.c = tableB.c;
```

#### Statement 2

```
merge into tableA using (select c from tableB where tableA.a=tableB.a and 
b='10') on (tableA.a = tableB.a) 
when matched update set tableA.c= tableB.c where tableA.c is null;
```

For e.g.,

tableA

```
a       b       c
100     10      null
100     20      null
100     30      null
100     40      null
100     50      null
```

tableB

```
a       b       c
100     10      99
100     20      88
100     30      77
100     40      66
```

After first merge

tableA

```
a       b       c
100     10      99
100     20      88
100     30      77
100     40      66
100     50      null
```

After second merge

tableA

```
a       b       c
100     10      99
100     20      88
100     30      77
100     40      66
100     50      99
```

First statement updates all the required rows except one which has no matching row in tableB. So in second merge statement I update that row with another value from some hardcoded row in tableB .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, this should help:

```
merge into tableA 
using (select tt.a, tt.b, b.c
          from (select tableA.a, tableA.b, nvl(tableB.b, '10') hardcoded_b
                  from tableA left join tableB on tableA.a = tableB.a and tableA.b = tableB.b) tt
               join tableB b on tt.a = b.a and tt.hardcoded_b = b.b) t
   on (tableA.a = t.a and tableA.b = t.b) 
  when matched then update set tableA.c = t.c;
```

In the subquery `t` I make a set of rows where value, absent in `tableB`, is filled with value from the hardcoded line.